Create user in congito during external signup by providing default phone_number if it doesn't exist
How to update phone number to default value if phone_number doesn't exist during signup.
Our cognito cannot have phone_number to have null so it needs to have default value.
The below code is written in Pre sign-up Lambda trigger
Below code doesn't seem to work when signup during External Azure Provider
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Pre Signup Congito")

    if event['triggerSource'] == "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider":
        request = event['request']
        user_attributes = request['userAttributes']

        # If no phone number initialize with default number
        if not user_attributes['phone_number']:
            user_attributes['phone_number'] = '+1888888888'
            user_attributes['phone_number_verified'] = 'false'

        request['userAttributes'] = user_attributes
        event['request'] = request

    # Return to Amazon Cognito
    return event

Below are the required attributes

Adding default phone number for cognito since its a required attribute.
During federated microsoft login I get the below error. So to avoid it... I am adding default phone number if it doesn't exist.
http://localhost:3000/login#error_description=Invalid+SAML+response+received%3A+Invalid+user+attributes%3A+phoneNumbers%3A+The+attribute+phoneNumbers+is+required+&error=server_error

"Doesn't seem to work". OK - So what happens? Is event a dictionary?

More code than needed to add the default phone number, but it's not clear where it fails. Did you check that event['triggerSource'] is indeed "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider" and how do you capture the returned "event" ?

@SIGHUP its a dictionary ...  I am just updating phone number and returning back..

@srn updated the orginal question and added more details...

@srn event['triggerSource'] is PreSignUp_ExternalProvider (Confirmed)
